# Burninate/clean up [project] and [projects]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request, clean-up

While there are a few cases where [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) (2,637 questions) could be applied, it is mostly used to just say "I'm working on a project", which most things are.  It should be burninated under [clause 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191): "Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?"

There are a few posts that use it logically, such as [In eclipse, how to have one project override class files of another project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27332328/3991344).  I'm considering logical use to be ones that are referring to projects themselves, as defined in the excerpt.

In the case of [projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projects), things are used more correctly.  However, it should probably be synonymized with [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project).  There's still a few fringe-quality posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060299/my-1st-project-i-just-need-a-few-pointers), though.

Comment: Project managers will be unhappy.

Comment: @Neolisk I think you are projecting.

Comment: @Yakk: Just a thought, I'm not throwing projectiles at anybody.

Comment: This post could need some more attention, these tags are just silly.

Comment: We do have a [duplicate link to here now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363346/1541563). Did get some decent attention but still no action, to my knowledge.

Comment: It's been 3 years. I'm a bit surprised this hasn't been dealt with yet. I cast my vote for "this is a useless tag".

Comment: @pushkin do you think that tag can be removed in one go or does it need a clean-up / retag as well?

Comment: @rene You're likely much more familiar with the burninating process than I. At the least, I'd remove the tag so that no one can tag their posts with this. Will this require first removing the tag from all posts? Can the purge be automated? I wouldn't think that retagging these posts would be *super* useful, though we could take a look at the roughly 400 unanswered posts and decide if the tag should be removed from them, or if we should create a more specific project tag for their purposes. I'm largely indifferent though.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like a plan @pushkin which you could write as an answer. Keep in mind that these requests are mostly dealt with by the community, that is you and me. Nothing happens with most of those requests because no-one wants to take on the busy-work, partly because a clear specific actionable plan to handle the burn is lacking.

Answer (score 3):

I think both of these tags are useless. They fit most of the criteria [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

This is an ambiguous meta tag.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

I don't believe it does.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

I suppose it is.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, it's ambiguous.

---

According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), I need to wait for a mod to approve the request before proceeding, but here is my action plan:

1. If there is no automated way of removing the tag from all questions (and that is required before we can remove the tag), then I'd first edit both of these tags to indicate to people not to use them and to prefer a more specific project tag like [ms-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-project) (which is in fact already mentioned on the tag wiki).
2. Then, we can at least go through the unanswered questions (~400 questions) and see if the tag should be removed or replaced by something more specific.
3. Then, I'd be fine with just removing the tags from all the questions unconditionally and finally, burninating the tag. Maybe we could sample a few of them (like the highest-voted ones) first.