# The Burninate [project]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request

I could be mistaken, but this tag seems about as helpful as something like [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/program), which is to say, it is not helpful here.

It currently has 529 followers and 3,367 questions.

Before burnination can begin, there is an ambiguity that needs to be dealt with first, so applicable questions need to be retagged manually. As indicated by the wiki for [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project):

> For questions related to Microsoft Project use the tag [ms-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-project).

### Burninate?

To review [the guidelines for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/313880):

#### 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?

A: Yes. No.

The tag does describe contents of the question (as almost all programming questions are related to a [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) of some sort), but it does not provide any **useful** description of the question. No one can be an expert in [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project). And since it is ambiguous with [ms-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-project) and [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) [apparently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363346/is-project-too-broad#comment557583_363346), it needs to go.

#### 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

A: Technically, yes.

Though by that criteria alone, [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/program) would be a valid tag.

#### 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

A: No.

As the tag can apply across all different languages, environments, stacks, etc., it **does not** provide any meaningful addition to posts.

#### 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

A: No(?)

As stated before, it needs to be replaced with [ms-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-project) in questions where that applies. According to [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363346/is-project-too-broad#comment557583_363346), others may need to be retagged with [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide). In other questions where it is used to signify the general term, it does mean the same thing, though.

Now that there are two ambiguous tags, [ms-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-project) and [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide), another question to consider is if this is worth the growing effort it appears to require?

### Possible Alternative to Burnination

We edit the [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) wiki to narrow the accepted criteria for usage of the tag, retag needed questions, but otherwise leave other questions alone.

### Answers

Answers to this request might argue for or against burnination, propose other alternatives, and / or propose a new wiki entry for [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) to make it narrower, should we decide to keep it.

Comment: On a side note, before the burnination is officially accepted, would it be okay to start retagging some of the applicable questions now, or would there be any harm in doing so?

Comment: While I don't  feel strongly about this tag, the counterargument is that project, defined as _a collection of files and resources used in the development of an application or service_ per the tag wiki, is a term that is used often in IDEs, and most questions refer to it in that regard. There's a lot of misuse of the tag, but all questions that properly use it form a distinct collection (mostly questions about IDEs, how they manage projects and files, how to organize and search through files in a project, etc.)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth then perhaps this complicates the process a bit. I'll go ahead and include that in the question, but would retagging those as [tag:ide] be a possible solution?

Comment: [tag:ide] is a very broad tag. This is a distinct subset. I'd personally refrain from retagging them [tag:ide] unless they would be orphaned otherwise (e.g. the combination [tag:visual-studio] + [tag:project] will probably contain questions about VS projects, but the combination [tag:ide] + [tag:visual-studio] will probably contain nothing in particular outside of visual studio)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I see your point. One thing I think you're wrong about is saying it's a distinct subset though. If that were true, every question tagged [tag:project] would also be tagged [tag:ide]. However, it's starting to look like a decent counter argument regardless, and I'm wondering if instead of burnination we need to change the wiki to reflect the tag should be used in cases where project layout is somehow relevant to the question.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, a more narrow excerpt with specific tag guidance certainly is welcome. This question is gathering some upvotes, imo we could wait for some more opinions before making a decision

Comment: Title suggestion: Does the [project] have too much scope?

Comment: Who is helped by that tag being present? I mean is somebody going to see a question tagged "project" and then think *Oh how interesting, I love questions that are specifically about a "project" which is a collection of files and resources. Let me go take a look!*. I can't imagine it, it is going to be paired with a more relevant tag that will draw the interest (SoapUI, Visual Studio, etc.). Meanwhile it is as ambiguous as you can make it and only too easy for people to start applying for no specific reason at all. Just burn that sucker.

Comment: Please note the existence of the [visual-studio-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-project) and [eclipse-project-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-project-file) tags. Any others that are similar?

Comment: The most popular combination is [java][project].  The [java] tag is certainly very broad with a million questions.  The only way you can tell that it is not actually about the Java language is by the presence of the [project] tag.  Don't screw that up.

Comment: Notably, project management questions are off-topic and should be asked at https://pm.stackexchange.com. The only kind of "projects" that are on-topic are projects being a collection of source code files. We also have [tag:project-management] which I believe people have tried to burn before.

Comment: Punny title candidate: Start a burninate project to burninate project?

Comment: @Lundin decided to go with a variant of your suggestion

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  &PatrickRoberts Maybe we can create a new [tag:ide-project] tag and use it to retag questions properly using [tag:project] to refer to IDE projects?

Comment: @robinCTS I dislike that suggestion, since it will be harder to find. I frequent the [tag:ms-access] tag, and about one in five questions that should have that tag are tagged [tag:Access] instead even though the excerpt explicitly states not to use that tag for it. If we don't blacklisted the project tag, I imagine something similar will happen

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'm not sure what you mean by *"harder to find"*. In my comment I meant that, in addition to blacklisting [tag:project], we could create [tag:ide-project] to use for the types of questions you alluded to in [this comment](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363346/?noredirect=1#comment557583_363346). I also forgot to mention that the new tag wiki should state that the tag should be used in conjunction with the appropriate IDE tag, like for example [tag:ms-access].

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Just read my first comment and realised that it doesn't read anything like what I intended it to.

Comment: What I mean is that, even though an excerpt might be explicit, and a more descriptive tag might exist, people working with a visual studio project will likely try to tag it [tag:visual-studio] [tag:project] without reading any excerpt. The tag [tag:ms-access] is an example where it goes wrong imo, that's why I've suggested to [burninate access](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356097/7296893) to keep people from using the wrong tag.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Thanks. Yeah, I definitely think [tag:access] should be burninated for similar reasons to [tag:project].

Answer (score 7):

> Is [project] too broad?

Yes. It's the definition of a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). The TL;DR principle is

> The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question.

Most of the terrible questions have to do with coding projects in general (and not a specific type of project). I don't think [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) is the solution to most. In fact I would say, for those questions that are salvageable, the tag should just be removed (except where a specific tag exists, like [ms-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-project), [visual-studio-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-project), etc). The good ones at least reference some other on-topic tag

> We edit the project wiki to narrow the accepted criteria for usage of the tag, retag needed questions, but otherwise leave other questions alone.

The reason we burninate in the first place is that the tag is drawing bad questions (bad tags encourage bad questions). Since the tag is not necessary for the on-topic questions, burnination is appropriate here

Comment: Burninating it and rettaging some to visual-studio-project, but not creating android-studio-project, r-studio-project, eclipse-project, etc. feels a bit weird to me. It's not a meta tag, it's a commonly used concept in IDEs. You can ask about it (since IDEs are on-topic), but it's pretty meaningless without  specifying the IDE. With it, it has meaning, and is narrow. Feels a bit like the [VBA or word-vba, excel-vba, etc. discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356080/7296893) to me.

Comment: I don't think it's meta, either: or at least, it's not _necessarily_ meta.  It may end up being used that way most of the time.  But *project* is a concept in and of itself.

Comment: I don't think it's so much *"bad tags encourage bad questions"* as the other way around. Users posting bad questions tend to tag incorrectly (and ignore specific instructions in the tag popup on when *not* to use it) / use bad tags.

Answer (score -3):

I think [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) does have *some* value, though it's unclear if that value is reflected in the questions it is tagged with, and perhaps that means its value is insufficient to exist.

I think one important subset of questions here are *tools that programmers use*, and a subset of *that* is not IDEs but specifically how to organize one's code for best effect.  This is analogous to, for example, using Subversion or Git.

While some of you probably think the concept of "how to organize your code by using a project" is obvious and not worth its own topic, many older programmers (meaning, people who programmed in the 1970s, for example) find the concept entirely odd.  In other languages, the concept of project doesn't exist.  This is a common issue in my language of choice - [sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sas) - where we have a relatively new IDE (ten years old, but that's relatively new for a programming language 50 years old) that people being using but don't know how to best utilize the "project" that comes with it as opposed to separate programs that they've been writing for decades, or their professors taught them to write.

And so, it is a concept that has some validity in asking - when to make a project as opposed to a single program, for example. How to best use projects - do we have one big project file for the entire application?  Do we have separate project files for different major elements of the application?

I don't know that there are all *that* many questions in this arena, but I think it's nonzero, and worth at least considering.